# C# WebBrowser get mouse click position

Tags: c#, browser

I have `WebBrowser` class and image loaded in it. After mouse click on the browser, I need to get mouse position - what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is actually pretty simple if your just looking for the screen coordinates.

```
// this probably should be in your form initialization
this.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(MouseClickEvent);

void MouseClickEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // do whatever you need with e.Location
}
```

if your strictly looking for the point in the browser, you need to consider the functions

```
browser.PointToClient();
browser.PointToScreen();
```

Comment: Is there any other way to capture point clicked directly on webbrowser control?

Comment: @UGEEN you can use the `ObjectForScripting` property to embed code to do this in the webbrowser. It's ugly to say the least. MSDN has some documentation on the process here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

Comment: ugh it's realy ugly;)-maybe better solution is to use AxWebBrowser - it's ugly too but not so scarry. Tahank you for your time and response Greg.